# audio file stop playing on a listview after several clicks?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, audio, media-player

I have created a ListView and an each ListView item has 2 TextViews, an image and an audio file. Everything works fine and the audio files are played, but when I click on items several times and scroll up and down, the audio file is not played. What is wrong at that part?

Here is my java code :

```
public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

    ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();

    words.add(new Word("one","un",R.drawable.number_one,R.raw.one));
    words.add(new Word("two","deux",R.drawable.number_two,R.raw.two));
     .......

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.numberViewlist);
    WordAdapter itemsAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, 
    words,R.color.category_numbers,listView);
    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
  }
}
```

and this is the code for the WordAdaper :

```
 lView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
     MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),currentWord.getsound());
     mp.start();
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if (mp != null) {
  if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.stop();
  }
  mp.release();
  mp = null;
}
```

Please refer this [Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()) !

Comment: I did all the modifications  you tell me but still have the same problem :